# How a script in PHP pings a URL after a interval of time?

Tags: php

Is there any possibility of a PHP or any script that can be configured to Ping a URL after a specified interval of time automatically? I want to stay awake heroku app from sleeping, i m using hobby account 7$/month.

Comment: Do you have access to crontab?

Comment: No, its shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty example..

```
<?php

while (true) // euuuuughh
{
    $throwAway = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
    sleep(10); // sleep for 10 seconds
}

?>
```

Hopefully you can take this and bend it to your needs.

You could also run this via command line and leave it running for a while to see if it helps.